# How to improve the efficiency of this SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery

I'm pretty average at SQL - not the best by any means.  I have the following SQL statement that I understand probably is not written with performance in mind:

```
select 
    COI1.EmailAddress, 
    COI1.DateTriggered as 'COIEmail1Date', 
    COI2.DateTriggered as 'COIEmail2Date' 
from 
    COITOUCH1_DE COI1
left join 
    COITOUCH2_DE COI2 on COI1.EmailAddress = COI2. EmailAddress 
where 
    COI1.EmailAddress not in (select EmailAddress from _Subscribers) 
    or COI2.EmailAddress not in (select EmailAddress from _Subscribers)
```

So in a nutshell, I need a list of records that are in the tables COITOUCH1_DE **OR** COITOUCH2_DE that **ARE NOT** in the _Subscribers table.  This query is taking forever - how can I make this more efficient?

Comment: If you want records that exist in both tables, change it to an `inner join`, for a start.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Sorry, I meant "OR"

Comment: Ok, then you actually need a `full outer join`. Currently rows that are only in COI2 will not be reported.

Comment: And as for optimization, I suggest you look at your execution plan (Query -> Include Actual Execution Plan in SSMS) to get some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for my first answer.  I thought you said BOTH COI tables must have the e-mail address.

If you want EITHER of the COI tables to have the e-mail address (but not _Subscribers), why not use a UNION instead?  Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT coi.email, coi.date 
FROM ((select EmailAddress as email, DateTriggered as date from COITOUCH1_DE)
    UNION
    (select EmailAddress as email, DateTriggered as date from COITOUCH2_DE)
    ) AS coi
    LEFT JOIN _Subscribers AS sub ON coi.EmailAddress = sub.EmailAddress
WHERE sub.EmailAddress IS NULL;
```

**Original Answer (thinking that you meant BOTH COI1 and COI2 must have the e-mail address):**

Your `not in` clauses are killing you.  Try a double join and check for null instead.

```
select COI1.EmailAddress, 
    COI1.DateTriggered as 'COIEmail1Date', 
    COI2.DateTriggered as 'COIEmail2Date' 
from COITOUCH1_DE COI1
    inner join COITOUCH2_DE COI2 on COI1.EmailAddress = COI2.EmailAddress
    left join _Subscribers SUB on COI1.EmailAddress = SUB.EmailAddress
where SUB.EmailAddress IS NULL;
```

You want your first join to be an inner join (since you said it must exist in BOTH of the first two tables), and you second join to be a left join so that you can see if there was NO corresponding record in the _Subscribers table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. the reason for not using a UNION is because I don't want duplicate email addresses... for example, if COITOUCH1_DE has an email address as well as COITOUCH2_DE, then there would be two individual records, where COI1.DateTriggered has a value for one and is NULL for the other, then the duplicate email address would be just the opposite - COI2.DateTriggered would have a value and COI1.DateTriggered would be NULL.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but UNION's not going to cross your records together.  If COI1 has 2 records: 

(a@a.com, 1/1/2011)
(b@b.com, 2/2/2012)

and COI2 has 2 records: 

(a@a.com, 1/1/2011)
(c@c.com, 3/3/2013)

then the union's going to have 4 records with two columns, and none of the values will be null:

(a@a.com, 1/1/2011)
(b@b.com, 2/2/2012)
(a@a.com, 1/1/2011)
(c@c.com, 3/3/2013)

I put a DISTINCT on the SELECT to get rid of the duplicate a's after the join/where.

Sure, if a@a.com has two different dates in the two different tables, DISTINCT will leave both. I think you'd want that.

Comment: My result set should include EmailAddress, COIEmail1Date, and COIEmail2Date.  COIEmail1Date and COIEmail2Date will either be both populated, or one of them would be NULL.  Currently, your statement brings back only one date column, not both...

Answer (score 1):

here is the SQL statement:

```
select COI1.EmailAddress, COI1.DateTriggered as COIEmail1Date, 
       COI2.DateTriggered as COIEmail2Date
from COITOUCH1_DE COI1 left join
     COITOUCH2_DE COI2
     on COI1.EmailAddress = COI2.EmailAddress 
where COI1.EmailAddress not in (select EmailAddress from _Subscribers) or 
      COI2.EmailAddress not in (select EmailAddress from _Subscribers);
```

A word of advice:  don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.

You can simplify the query, because `COI2.EmailAddress` is the same as `COI1.EmailAddress`:

```
select COI1.EmailAddress, COI1.DateTriggered as COIEmail1Date, 
       COI2.DateTriggered as COIEmail2Date
from COITOUCH1_DE COI1 left join
     COITOUCH2_DE COI2
     on COI1.EmailAddress = COI2.EmailAddress 
where COI1.EmailAddress not in (select EmailAddress from _Subscribers);
```

As for the query, it would benefit from indexes.  I would recommend: `_Subscribers(EmailAddress)` and `COITOUCH2_DE(EmailAddress)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that I think will actually get you the result you want.

```
select 
    COI1.EmailAddress, 
    COI1.DateTriggered as 'COIEmail1Date', 
    COI2.DateTriggered as 'COIEmail2Date' 
from COITOUCH1_DE COI1
full outer join COITOUCH2_DE COI2 on COI1.EmailAddress = COI2.EmailAddress 
where isnull(COI1.EmailAddress, COI2.EmailAddress)
      not in (select EmailAddress from _Subscribers)
```

You should take a look at the execution plan (Query -> Include Actual Execution Plan in SQL Server Management Studio) to see what any problems might be. You may just need an index or two.